# Way to efficiently add push key to pushed object. - Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my app users are able create new Jobs and register them under their own UID.

```
let newJobRef = firebase.database().ref(`/jobs/serviceUsers/activeJobs/${currentUser.uid}`);
newJobRef.push(job)
```

I know that after the promise has resolved, you get the snapshot object which has the push-key stored as `snapshot.key` like so:

```
.then(snapshot => {
  let myPushKey = snapshot.key;
  // do more stuff here
}
```

However, it is important in my app to store this key within the Job object itself. So I have to make a second round trip and update the recently pushed job to add the push key to it, as a key-value pair.

My question is: Is this the right way to do this? Is there any other way to add the push key to the object in a one way trip? (Not including cloud functions). I was hoping for some reserved firebase-syntax or word that would do this automatically when it hits the DB, but have found nothing.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easy to do once you realize that `push()` can also be called without a value:

```
let userRef = firebase.database().ref(`/jobs/serviceUsers/activeJobs/${currentUser.uid}`);
let newJobRef = userRef.push();
job.key = newJobRef.key;
newJobRef.set(job);
```

The call to `push()` is a pure client-side call, it just generates a reference with a unique ID. The call to `set()` is the one that writes the values to the database here.

Note that storing the key of the object inside that object is kind of an anti-pattern. While it's often necessary to have both the key and the value in the program, I usually do that by passing the snapshot around (which has `.key` and `.val()` already) or by injecting the key into the object upon reading (instead of in the database itself).